# Exception while creating PDF file from Asciidoctor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, asciidoc

I am getting exception while creating pdf file from ascii doc files using the following libraries in Spring boot application.

```
org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:1.6.0-alpha.3
org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.11
org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-epub3:1.5.0-alpha.6
```

I found similar issues reported earlier tried by setting class loader but no success.

The exception shown is

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- asciidoctor
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:944) ~[jruby-core-9.1.2.0.jar!/:?]
        at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55) ~[?:?]
        at RUBY.<top>(<script>:9) ~[?:?]
```

My code looks like this. The path is the directory where ascii doc are stored.

```
final Asciidoctor asciidoctor = create();
asciidoctor.renderDirectory(new AsciiDocDirectoryWalker(path), options().backend("pdf").get());
asciidoctor.shutdown();
```

Comment: What is the exception? Do mention that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution from Spring boot team. Please refer Spring boot Github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7399) for more details